# Magento - Show simple product image and description

Tags: magento

I really need the following in magento. When a customer shows the config product and select the color the simple product image and description should show. I am already using the SCP Products but then both the color and size need to be chosen or else it will not change the picture. In addition this module changes the way the emails items look and also the pdf's

Anybody knows a different solution?

---

Thanks for the reply, let me split this in 2 problems I have.

Problem 1:

When I use SCP he doesn't show the color and size anymore on the items table in my emails and pdf's. So it's not easy to see anymore which product I need to grab for delivery.

Problem 2:

Indeed he needs both dropdowns, size and color to be changed to show the simple product details. This needs to change to only color. I found a post which stated some code to get this working but's not for me.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/site.php/viewthread/30929/P0/

So I changed the attribID I found trough mysql and changed the value color to my colorattribute which is kleurproduct

Added this code

```
Product.Config.prototype.reloadPrice = function() {
var childProductId = this.getMatchingSimpleProduct();
var childProducts = this.config.childProducts;
var attribID = 158;
var kleurproductDropdown = document.getElementById('attribute' + attribID);
var kleurproductSelectedIndex = kleurproductDropdown.selectedIndex;
var kleurproduct_value  = kleurproductDropdown.options[kleurproductSelectedIndex].text;
//if the price ranges option is checked in the backend then a colon and the price is added to the dropdown
if (kleurproduct_value.indexOf(':') > -1) {
    kleurproduct_value = kleurproduct_value.substr(0,kleurproduct_value.indexOf(':'));
}
var usingZoomer = false;
if(this.config.imageZoomer){
    usingZoomer = true;
}

if (childProductId){
    var price = childProducts[childProductId]["price"];
    var finalPrice = childProducts[childProductId]["finalPrice"];
    optionsPrice.productPrice = finalPrice;
    optionsPrice.productOldPrice = price;
    optionsPrice.reload();
    optionsPrice.reloadPriceLabels(true);
    optionsPrice.updateSpecialPriceDisplay(price, finalPrice);
    this.updateProductShortDescription(childProductId);
    this.updateProductDescription(childProductId);
    this.updateProductName(childProductId);
    this.updateProductAttributes(childProductId);
    this.updateFormProductId(childProductId);
    this.addParentProductIdToCartForm(this.config.productId);
    this.showCustomOptionsBlock(childProductId, this.config.productId);
    if (usingZoomer) {
        this.showFullImageDiv(childProductId, this.config.productId);
    }else{
        this.updateProductImage(childProductId);
    }

}
//added else if for when just a kleurproduct is selected
else if (kleurproduct_value) {
    for (var product in childProducts) {
        //find the kleurproduct attribute in the childProduct html
        var colStartPos = childProducts[product].productAttributes.indexOf('<th class="label">kleurproduct</th>')
        colStartPos = childProducts[product].productAttributes.indexOf('>', colStartPos + 28)
        var colEndPos = childProducts[product].productAttributes.indexOf('</td>', colStartPos)
        //check each child product for matching kleurproduct
        if (childProducts[product].productAttributes.substr(colStartPos + 1, colEndPos - colStartPos - 1)==kleurproduct_value) {
            childProductId = product;
            var price = childProducts[childProductId]["price"];
            var finalPrice = childProducts[childProductId]["finalPrice"];
            optionsPrice.productPrice = finalPrice;
            optionsPrice.productOldPrice = price;
            optionsPrice.reload();
            optionsPrice.reloadPriceLabels(true);
            optionsPrice.updateSpecialPriceDisplay(price, finalPrice);
            this.updateProductShortDescription(childProductId);
            this.updateProductDescription(childProductId);
            this.updateProductName(childProductId);
            this.updateProductAttributes(childProductId);
            this.updateFormProductId(childProductId);
            this.addParentProductIdToCartForm(this.config.productId);
            this.showCustomOptionsBlock(childProductId, this.config.productId);
            if (usingZoomer) {
                this.showFullImageDiv(childProductId, this.config.productId);
            }else{
                this.updateProductImage(childProductId);
             }
            //one product was found, exit the loop
            break;
         }
    }
}
else {
    var cheapestPid = this.getProductIdOfCheapestProductInScope("finalPrice");
    //var mostExpensivePid = this.getProductIdOfMostExpensiveProductInScope("finalPrice");
    var price = childProducts[cheapestPid]["price"];
    var finalPrice = childProducts[cheapestPid]["finalPrice"];
    optionsPrice.productPrice = finalPrice;
    optionsPrice.productOldPrice = price;
    optionsPrice.reload();
    optionsPrice.reloadPriceLabels(false);
    optionsPrice.updateSpecialPriceDisplay(price, finalPrice);
    this.updateProductShortDescription(false);
    this.updateProductDescription(false);
    this.updateProductName(false);
    this.updateProductAttributes(false);
    this.showCustomOptionsBlock(false, false);
    if (usingZoomer) {
        this.showFullImageDiv(false, false);
    }else{
        this.updateProductImage(false);
    }
}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCP extension does a number of things.  Fist is the UI enhancements you've mentioned where the image and other product details change, to match the specific simple product selected.  The other thing SCP does is to change the way Magento's pricing works so that when a configurable product is purchased the customer is charged whatever price is on the simple product variant selected rather than the parent configurable price.  The change in pricing logic is what's behind the changes to email and pdf formats.

When a simple product is linked into a configurable by two different attributes the user will need to select both in order to uniquely identify the specific simple product and therefore the image to display.

In a clothing example though, once a color is selected an image could be shown, because in most cases the images will be the same for each size.  The SCP extension supplies it's own JavaScript which responds to change events on the select boxes to trigger the Ajax loads, etc.  It would be possible to modify this JavaScript code to once a color is selected, locate the first size, and the fist corresponding simple product and load it's images.

Comment: Hi Jim, hope you can help me on the updates I put in my original post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this new module that does a lot more then SCP

[SDOCP - Simple details on configurable products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sdocp-simple-details-on-configurable-products.html)